# Why can't I build a city here?

Tags: civilization-6

I cannot build a city with my settler in all the red area and I don't get why.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Settler Lens](https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Lens_(Civ6)#Settler) tells you where you can settle.

- Red means you cannot settle here. You are either too close to another city, or the terrain is not suitable for founding a city (e.g. sea/ocean, mountain/volcano, Natural Wonder, etc.)
- Gray means your city won't get any Housing bonus. It will have a harder time growing.
- Light green means your city will get +1 Housing bonus.
- Dark green means your city will get +3 Housing bonus. It will grow more easily.

You can't found cities within 3 hexes of another city. This means that between your city and the next, there must be a distance of at least 3 hexes.

If you look at your screenshot, you'll notice that the majority of red tiles are within 3 hexes of another city.

[image: Annotated screenshot]
<sub>Click on image to see a larger version</sub>

The rest are probably also in range of another city, but we can't see them. In the upper part of the screenshot, there's likely a city above the "City?" marker, outside of the screenshot. In the bottom part, the city is most likely hidden somewhere behind the fog of war.

---

You also can't found cities within the borders of another nation, but all the borders in this screenshot are smaller than the 3 hex radius.

Comment: Worth noting that the red and green overlay that appears when you try to build a city is the UI telling you what tiles are available. Red is not available, light green is available with no housing bonus and the darker green is available with a housing bonus.

Comment: @Colin, thanks. I didn't think about explaining the meaning of the colors.